# How to change the border and background color of css class with colon and tilde using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

im new to using jQuery.
how can I update the border and background color using jQuery? i think my problem here is the jQuery selector, but how to create this jQuery selector?

```
$('.cls-box .cls-ctrl-input:bubble ~ .cls-ctrl-label::before')
.css('border-color','unset !important')
.css('background-color', 'unset !important'); - not working :(

.cls-box .cls-ctrl-input:bubble ~ .cls-ctrl-label::before {
  border-color: #211dff;
  background-color: #211dff;
}
```

TIA

Comment: try: $('.cls-box').css('border-color','#ff0000').css('background-color','#00ff00')

Comment: $('.cls-box .cls-ctrl-input:bubble ~ .cls-ctrl-label::before').css('border-color','#ff0000').css('background-color','#00ff00')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using javascript (or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Comment: You can find the JQuery `.css()` documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @ChrisBerlin its not working.

Comment: @CBroe i dont quite follow which ones but promising i think. but from my css, the :bubble and ~tilde is confusing, dont know how to use that in jQuery.

Comment: i think my problem here is the selector composition.

Comment: The tilde is the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator), that should present no problem in jQuery at all. The `::before` pseudo element however _can not_ be accessed via JavaScript, as the mentioned duplicate explains.

Comment: And in general, you should try and manipulate/set _inline_ styles as little as possible, and rather handle what _can_ be handled via your stylesheet, directly in there. If the colors you want to set here are not “dynamic” - then you should add a rule to your systelsheet that formats the target elements differently via an additional class, and then you just set that class via JS, not the styles themselves.

Comment: @IsmailVittal yes thats the standard for setting the css but I cannot compose the right jQuery selector.

Comment: @CBroe i think the toggle class is cls-ctrl-label, but how about the bubble?

Comment: try to add/remove class and from CSS change the border and background color

Comment: _“but how about the bubble?”_ – I have no idea what `:bubble` is supposed to be in the first place, I can’t find any documentation for that anywhere. It’s not part of the “well-known” pseudo classes listed in the MDN either, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Comment: @CBroe i traced the bubble from the js plugin, is just a boolean variable.

Comment: But that doesn’t explain what `.cls-ctrl-input:bubble` is supposed to be. I don’t think the mere existence of a variable in a script somewhere, will make the browser understand unknown pseudo classes in a CSS selector …

Comment: I was able to fix in jQuery not using css. Thanks to all who responded, i appreciate it.